# Determine if today's date is in a range of two dates on iOS

Tags: iphone, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare two dates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c)

I'd like to pop up a message in one of my apps when the date is in the range of two dates (e.g. the holiday period)

So like

```
if(dateInRangeof:date1, date2){True}else{false}
```

Looking for any code snippets or apis to look at. 
Cheers

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c), I guess it'll be very helpful.

Comment: I do not view this as duplicate. The answer below answers the specific question concisely.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date inRangeFirstDate:(NSDate *)firstDate lastDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {
   return [date compare:firstDate] == NSOrderedDescending &&
          [date compare:lastDate]  == NSOrderedAscending;
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder this is not inclusive. Inclusive would be `return !([date compare:firstDate] == NSOrderedAscending) && !([date compare:lastDate] == NSOrderedDescending;)`

Comment: Swift: ```func isDate (date : NSDate, inRange fromDate : NSDate, toDate : NSDate, inclusive : Bool) -> Bool {
        if inclusive
        {
            return !(date.compare (fromDate) == .OrderedAscending) && !(date.compare (toDate) == .OrderedDescending)
        }
        else
        {
           return date.compare (fromDate) == .OrderedDescending && date.compare (toDate) == .OrderedAscending
        }
    }
    ```