# iOS 7: Convert NSDate to string with custom timezone and get back new NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I wish to modify current system time (set a custom `NSTimeZone`) and get back a new `NSDate` object.

### The code I've made

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSLog(@"System time: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Aqtobe"]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Aqtobe time: %@", dateString);
```

### The output

```
System time: 2014-02-05 10:00:46 +0000

Aqtobe time: 2014-02-05 15:00:46 +0500
```

But if I try to get new NSDate object from Aqtobe time:

```
NSLog(@"New NSDate: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

I get

```
New NSDate: 2014-02-05 10:02:40 +0000
```

Where I was wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: `NSDate` will always return GMT. You can format it to whatever timezone you want when you print it (like you did). You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214947/help-me-understand-nsdate-date)

Comment: I don't completely understand. You want to check if a date is between two dates?

Comment: I'll write it as an answer due to lack of room.

Comment: You are not providing the timezone.. Default timezone is GMT. So it is providing that same date

Answer (score 3):

NSDate always returns date in GMT +0:00.
So, it (NSDate object) always have correct converted value but in GMT +0:00.
So for using it as text you will always have to use same date formatter with same zone.
If you want to use date as string from date in other places (out of dateformatter object scope), it is better to make special method for conversion.

It is explained clearly below with example:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";

NSLog(@"System time: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Aqtobe"]];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Aqtobe time: %@", dateString);

// date will always contain value in GMT +0:00
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"New NSDate (NSDate): %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

// converts date into string
NSLog(@"New NSDate (NSString): %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

For detailed explaination you can refer this question: [Does [NSDate date] return the local date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214947/help-me-understand-nsdate-date)

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` has many methods for comparing date such as `isEqualToDate:` (for a more detailed of the methods and usage you can see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c)).
This method, that I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276187/determine-if-todays-date-is-in-a-range-of-two-dates-on-ios), will let you determine if `date` is between `firstDate` and `lastDate`.

```
- (BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date inRangeFirstDate:(NSDate *)firstDate lastDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {
   return [date compare:firstDate] == NSOrderedDescending &&
          [date compare:lastDate]  == NSOrderedAscending;
}
```

I hope this is what you meant. If not please explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I've found the method how to check if date between 2 dates. My problem: I got 2 dates (called startTime and endTime) from server API (there are already with Aqtobe timezone `"start_time":"2000-01-01T15:00:00Z","end_time":"2000-01-01T16:00:00Z"`) and I have to check if my system time (It must be with Aqtobe timezone!) is between these 2 dates.

Comment: I've tried to use `[dateFormatter dateFromString]`. But it takes my system date without timezone correction which I've explained in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` to create a new date. From the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/datesandtimes/datesandtimes.html)

> Creating Dates with Time Zones
>
> Time zones play an important part in determining when dates take
>   place. Consider a simple calendar application that keeps track of
>   appointments. For example, say you live in Chicago and you have a
>   dentist appointment coming up at 10:00 AM on Tuesday. You will be in
>   New York for Sunday and Monday, however. When you created that
>   appointment it was done with the mindset of an absolute time. That
>   time is 10:00 AM Central Time; when you go to New York, the time
>   should be presented as 11:00 AM because you are in a different time
>   zone, but it is the same absolute time. On the other hand, if you
>   create an appointment to wake up and exercise every morning at 7:00
>   AM, you do not want your alarm to go off at 1:00 PM simply because you
>   are on a business trip to Dublin—or at 5:00 AM because you are in Los
>   Angeles.
>
> NSDate objects store dates in absolute time. For example, the date
>   object created in Listing 16 represents 4:00 PM CDT, 5:00 EDT, and so
>   on.
>
> Listing 16  Creating a date from components using a specific time zone

```
NSCalendar *gregorian=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"]];

NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init]; [timeZoneComps setHour:16];
//specify whatever day, month, and year is appropriate
NSDate *date=[gregorian dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps];
```

> If you need to create a date that is independent of timezone, you can store the
>   date as an NSDateComponents object—as long as you store some reference
>   to the corresponding calendar.
>
> In iOS, NSDateComponents objects can contain a calendar, a timezone,
>   and a date object. You can therefore store the calendar along with the
>   components. If you use the date method of the NSDateComponents class
>   to access the date, make sure that the associated timezone is
>   up-to-date.

Anyway, keep in mind that a date is a unique point in time. What you display to the user is different based on their locale and time zone.