# How to check if 2 Dates have a difference of 30days?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I calculate the difference between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371757/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates)
>   [NSDate, comparing two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781467/nsdate-comparing-two-dates)

I have got two dates. How to check if theres a difference of 30 days in between them?
I actually have an In-App purchase which needs to be disabled after every 30-days of purchase.
When the user buys the feature, the Date is saved and so I need to check the dates. If 30-days have passed, I need to disable the feature again.

Comment: Please learn to use the search function on Stack Overflow. This question has been asked many many times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the difference between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371757/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates), [Number of days between two NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert both dates to seconds with timeIntervalSince1970 and then check if difference is bigger than 2592000 (30*24*60*60 which is 30 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds).

```
NSTimeInterval difference = [date1 timeIntervalSince1970] - [date2 timeIntervalSince1970];

if(difference >2592000)
{
 //do your stuff here
}
```

EDIT:
For more compact version you can use [- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188--initWithTimeInterval_sinceDate_)

```
NSTimeInterval difference = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
if(difference >2592000)
{
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: this will fail for DST times.

Comment: @vikingosegundo really? why would that fail?

Comment: because not every day has 24 hours. In regions with DST one day has 23, one 25.

Comment: @vikingosegundo yes, that's true, user might get 2 hours less or more of subscription.

Comment: You thought 39 month about this? Wow, you are a thorough thinker.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the start and end NSDate in following manner:

```
    NSDate *date_Start;
    NSDate *date_End;
    NSCalendar *cal=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components=[cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date_Start toDate:date_End options:0];
    int days=[components day];
    if(days>30){
     //Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a date which is +30days from now :

```
NSDate *thrityDaysPlus = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600*24*30]
```

and then simply compare it to your saved date

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");        

} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");

}
```

Comment: will fail when it comes to DST