# How to Sort array based on date and time

Tags: ios

i have date string in form of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" i have some 100 obhjects in an array with different date and time.now my question is how to sort this array based on time and date, i tried in many ways but no use .can any one help me .thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711360/how-to-sort-the-array-that-contains-date-in-strings-in-ascending-order------ or --------- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132806/sort-nsarray-of-date-strings-or-objects..

Comment: Check out the NSDate [comp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781467/nsdate-comparing-two-dates) method

Comment: Do you mean you have dates in string format?  Or do you mean you have NSDate objects?

Answer (score 0):

used this method for sort an array.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [detailsArray sortArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

May be help for you

Comment: i want to sort array based on time and date i want to sort latest one

Comment: Is above code not sort you date array? I am using same approach and it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of strings, take advantage of your date format and just sort it lexically.

```
NSArray* sorted = [dates sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString* a, NSString* b) {
    return [a compare:b];
}];
```

If you actually have an array of NSDate objects, use the NSDate compare functions, using almost identical code (compare: works to compare two homogenous data types in many cases)

```
NSArray* sorted = [dates sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSDate* a, NSDate* b) {
    return [a compare:b];
}];
```

With the simplicity of the comparator, you can actually just use the selector directly:

```
NSArray* sorted = [dates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```