# How to compare current date to previous date in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nsdate

I would like to compare the current date with another date, and if that is date is earlier than the current date, then I should stop the next action. How can I do this?

I have todays date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. I need to check this condition

```
if([displaydate text]<currentdate)
{
    //stop next action 
}
```

Here if `displaydate` is less than todays date then it has to enter that condition.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; // it will give you current date
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateWithString:@"xxxxxx"]; // your date 

NSComparisonResult result; 
//has three possible values: NSOrderedSame,NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedAscending

result = [today compare:newDate]; // comparing two dates

if(result==NSOrderedAscending)
    NSLog(@"today is less");
else if(result==NSOrderedDescending)
    NSLog(@"newDate is less");
else
    NSLog(@"Both dates are same");
```

got your solution from this answer [How to compare two dates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c)

Comment: It is not equal to I should compare whether it is less than todays date ?

Comment: check my updated answer visit the link in my answerd i defiantly sure u got your solution my frnd

Comment: In the above answer u gave I have modified it as NSDate *newDate=[NSDate dateWithString:@"%@",[displaydate text]];but I m getting newDate as nil eventhough there is value in displaydate i.e 2011-11-02..Can u please tell me y ?

Comment: Its great dude.. It helps me out

Comment: @NitinGohel Great Solution

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative** to `@NNitin Gohel's` answer.

Compare using `NSTimeInterval` ie `NSDate` `timeIntervalSince1970`:

```
NSTimeInterval *todayTimeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval *previousTimeInterval = [previousdate timeIntervalSince1970];

if(previousTimeInterval < todayTimeInterval)
   //prevous date is less than today
else if (previousTimeInterval == todayTimeInterval)
   //both date are equal
else 
   //prevous date is greater than today
```

Comment: When I try ur code im getting err.I have to get todays date in yyyy-MM-dd format and for that Im doing like this : now = [NSDate date]; NSDateFormatter *df=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease]; df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; and now I need to compare this with a Datepicker selected date which should also be in yyyy-MM-dd format..This is what Im doing NSDateFormatter *df=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease]; df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; NSArray *temp=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:DatePicker.date]] componentsSeparatedByString:@""];How can I proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a closer look at this [Tutorial about NSDateFormatter](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatter-examples.html) and when you have your NSDate object you can compare it to another NSDate and get an NSTimeInterval which is the difference in seconds.

```
NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval interval = [nowDate timeIntervalSinceDate:pastDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Some methods of `NSDate` class are:

1. `isEarlierThanDate`. // using this method you can find out the date is previous or not..
2. `isLaterThanDate`
3. `minutesAfterDate`.
4. `minutesBeforeDate`. etc..

also see this link with many methods of NSDate in iPhone SDK..

[how-to-real-world-dates-with-the-iphone-sdk](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2010/03/how-to-real-world-dates-with-the-iphone-sdk/2/)

**Update**

```
//Current Date
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

use this bellow method for convert NSString date to NSDate format just paste this method in your.m file

```
- (NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *) date {
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDate *nowDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
// NSLog(@"date============================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : %@", date);
date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000" withString:@""];
nowDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
// NSLog(@"date============================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : %@", nowDate);
return nowDate;
}
```

after that when you want to use it just use like bellow..

```
NSDate *tempDate2 = [self convertStringToDate:yourStringDate];
```

and then try to compare like this..

```
if (tempDate2 > nowDate)
```

Comment: I have to get todays date in yyyy-MM-dd format and for that I m doing like this : now = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *df=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
        df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; and now I need to compare this with a Datepicker selected date which should also be in yyyy-MM-dd format..This is what I m doing   NSDateFormatter *df=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
    df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    NSArray *temp=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:DatePicker.date]] componentsSeparatedByString:@""];How can I proceed further  ?

Comment: how can I compare this date with the datepickers selected date which is also in yyyy-MM-dd.I took datepickers date in NSArray .

Comment: see this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c

Comment: yes its also easy you have an array you can compare it with [yourArray objectAtIndex:intValue]; // here give integer value

Comment: @Joshi I have tried this :  now = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *df=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
        df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; How to take it in a some variable and then compare because when i see in formatter it is showing <NSDateFormatter: 0x4e5d320> and then I have date in textfield like this :2011-11-02 .How can I compare Please tell me