# Conversion of NSString into the NSDate is giving wrong value and format in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I want to compare two dates.For that i have to dates in two strings(fromDates and toDates).

here fromDate is showing the correct value in console.

```
//Console.
19/12/2012 from date is
```

After the NSDateFormatter process im getting wrong format and date and sometime it is showing NULL.

```
//console
First = (null)
```

I used the below method.

```
if (fromDate) {
        self.printFromDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",curBtn.dateString];
        fromDates = self.printFromDate.text;
        NSLog(@"%@ from date is",fromDates);
       dtFormatter  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *strDate = [dtFormatter dateFromString:fromDates];
        NSLog(@"First = %@",strDate);    
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me where im goin wrong.i completly stuck here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: your stringDate and NSDateFormatter's dateformat should have same format to convert into date.

Comment: Dont you think your date format should be

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c

Comment: what the mean by compare...?? what you want after compare..

Answer (score 3):

Your date formatter doesn't follow the string format.

I think you're looking for this:

```
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *date1 = [dtFormatter dateFromString:fromDates];
NSDate *date2 = [dtFormatter dateFromString:anotherDate];

if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending)
    NSLog(@"date1 comes first");        
else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending)
    NSLog(@"date2 comes first");
else
    NSLog(@"date1 is the same date as date2");
```

Comment: you are correct.now it is showing like this  First = 2012-12-28 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: if suppose i want in this format 28/12/2012,how to set it.can you please help me

Comment: That is the the `description` format of an NSDate. To convert it back to an NSString, you can use the same formatter and `[dtFormatter stringFromDate:date]`

Comment: But at that point, what is the point of using a date formatter?

Comment: i wnat to compare two dates.thats all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20504/discussion-between-suji-and-john)

Answer (score 1):

```
        dtFormatter  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        NSDate *strDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        strDate = [dtFormatter dateFromString:fromDates];
        NSLog(@"First = %@",strDate);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.