# NSDateComponents comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdatecomponents

I would like to compare to NSDates but only with regard to hour and minute. The first date is given from an array, the second one is the current. I didn't arrive with this method:

```
 NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                                fromDate:date
                                                  toDate:currentDate options:0];
```

Any simple and good idea to solve my problem?

**EDIT:**
User 'sunny' posted some further methods to solve my problem: [How to compare two dates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp1 = [calendar components: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit
fromDate: date1];

NSDateComponents *comp2 = [calendar components: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit
fromDate: date2];
```

Now you have all the data you need to compare the two dates.

```
comp1.hour > comp2.hour
comp1.minute > comp2.minute
```

Comment: Your forgot the * ;) But thanks for this very cool workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                                              fromDate:date
                                                                toDate:currentDate
                                                               options:0];

if (components.hour==0&&components.minute==0) {
    NSLog(@"Equal time");
}
```