# Comparing equality of two NSDate objects gives unexpected results

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am running this for loop which deletes an indexValue if a condition is met. I am comparing two `NSDate` objects and for some reason it is not working. According to the log the `NSDate` objects match exactly.

Please guide me here.

**Code**

```
for (int u=0 ; u<arraywithDateAddedKeyss.count ; u++)
        {
            NSLog(@"arraywithDateAddedKeyss: %@ == Array 5: %@",arraywithDateAddedKeyss[u],oldArray[5]);

            if (arraywithDateAddedKeyss[u] == oldArray[5])
            {
                [arraywithDateAddedKeyss removeObjectAtIndex:u];

                [userDefaults setObject:arraywithDateAddedKeyss forKey:@"arraywithReminderDateKeys"];

                [userDefaults synchronize];


                NSLog(@"Object Removed from array1");


            }
        }
```

**NSLog data**

```
arraywithDateAddedKeyss: 2014-02-01 09:01:20 +0000 == Array 5: 2014-02-01 09:01:20 +0000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot compare two dates using `==`.

`==` compares pointer equality, meaning that you are checking for object identity rather than equality.
(Worth reading on the subject: http://nshipster.com/equality/)

Use the [`isEqualToDate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/isEqualToDate:) method of `NSDate` for such purpose

```
NSDate *date1 = arraywithDateAddedKeyss[u];
NSDate *date2 = oldArray[5];

if ([date1 isEqualToDate:date2]) {
   ...
}
```

For other ways of comparing `NSDate` objects, you can refer to: [How to compare two dates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Change your if to isEqual, you should use it insteat of ==:

```
if ([arraywithDateAddedKeyss[u] isEqual:oldArray[5]])
{
    //Add this log for debuting
    NSLog(@"Dates are equal");
    //.. your code here
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two `pointer` using `==` operator. Better use below code .. [See apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-compare_)

```
NSDate *date = oldArray[5];
for(NSDate *dateToBeCompare in arraywithDateAddedKeyss)
{
    if ([date compare:dateToBeCompare] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
           //Your code here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
 for (int u=arraywithDateAddedKeyss.count-1; u>=0 ; u--)
    {
        if ([arraywithDateAddedKeyss[u] compare:oldArray[5]] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [arraywithDateAddedKeyss removeObjectAtIndex:u];
            [userDefaults setObject:arraywithDateAddedKeyss forKey:@"arraywithReminderDateKeys"];
            [userDefaults synchronize];
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** You must loop your array from the end to the beginning if you want to remove an object at some index