# Check whether time falls between two time iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two times let say 8.40am and 4.00pm,
What i want to do is, want to check whether current time falls between given time or not ?

I have tried this code snippet but it is not working :(
can you please help me out where i am making mistake ?

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger currHr = [components hour];
    NSInteger currtMin = [components minute];

    NSString startTime = @"21:00";
    NSString endTime = @"07:00";
NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:startTime,endTime, nil];

    int stHr = [[[[arr objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    int stMin = [[[[arr objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    int enHr = [[[[arr objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    int enMin = [[[[arr objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

    int formStTime = (stHr*60)+stMin;
    int formEnTime = (enHr*60)+enMin;

    int nowTime = (currHr*60)+currtMin;

    if(nowTime >= formStTime && nowTime <= formEnTime) {
        NSLog(@"Btween......");
    }
```

***Thnaks in advance***

**EDIT:**

```
NSDateComponents *openingTime = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    openingTime.hour = [timeA integerValue]; //8
    openingTime.minute = [timeB integerValue];  //45

    NSDateComponents *closingTime = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    closingTime.hour = [timeC integerValue]; //4
    closingTime.minute = [timeD integerValue];  //43


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];

        NSString *nowTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDate *now = [formatter dateFromString:nowTimeString]; //3:30

    NSDateComponents *currentTime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond
                                                                    fromDate:now];

    NSMutableArray *times = [@[openingTime, closingTime, currentTime] mutableCopy];
    [times sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDateComponents *t1, NSDateComponents *t2) {
        if (t1.hour > t2.hour) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        if (t1.hour < t2.hour) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        // hour is the same
        if (t1.minute > t2.minute) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        if (t1.minute < t2.minute) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        // hour and minute are the same
        if (t1.second > t2.second) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        if (t1.second < t2.second) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        return NSOrderedSame;

    }];

    if ([times indexOfObject:currentTime] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"We are Open!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sorry, we are closed!");
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c)?

Comment: I do not want to compare two dates.. i want to check time exist between two time

Comment: It is actually two comparisons of dates. Just convert them to `NSDate` objects and use methods from iOS SDK

Comment: Why down vote did i asked any thing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- create date components for opening and closing time.
- create date components with hour, minute, second from date to check
- place opening, closing and current time in an array
- sort array. if current time is at index 1, it lies between opening and closing time

---

```
NSDateComponents *openingTime = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
openingTime.hour = 8;
openingTime.minute = 40;

NSDateComponents *closingTime = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
closingTime.hour = 16;
closingTime.minute = 0;

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *currentTime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond
                                                                fromDate:now];

NSMutableArray *times = [@[openingTime, closingTime, currentTime] mutableCopy];
[times sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDateComponents *t1, NSDateComponents *t2) {
    if (t1.hour > t2.hour) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (t1.hour < t2.hour) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    // hour is the same
    if (t1.minute > t2.minute) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (t1.minute < t2.minute) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    // hour and minute are the same
    if (t1.second > t2.second) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (t1.second < t2.second) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;

}];

if ([times indexOfObject:currentTime] == 1) {
    NSLog(@"We are Open!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Sorry, we are closed!");
}
```

Comment: Dude see my EDIT in the question i have triied your code snippet it shows me `Sorry, we are closed!` my opening time is `8` and `45` in AM and closing time is `4` and`43` in PM and current time is `3:30`

Comment: 4:43 is 24 hour. try 16:43. and I am not your dude.

Comment: Thanx for helping, problem solved +1 for your answer

Comment: You spared my time ! Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
NSString *startTimeString = @"08:00 AM";
NSString *endTimeString = @"06:00 PM";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

NSString *nowTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

int startTime   = [self minutesSinceMidnight:[formatter dateFromString:startTimeString]];
int endTime  = [self minutesSinceMidnight:[formatter dateFromString:endTimeString]];
int nowTime     = [self minutesSinceMidnight:[formatter dateFromString:nowTimeString]];;


if (startTime <= nowTime && nowTime <= endTime)
{
    NSLog(@"Time is between");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Time is not between");
}


-(int) minutesSinceMidnight:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:date];
    return 60 * (int)[components hour] + (int)[components minute];        
}
```

Check the screenshot -

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it gives me error here `int nowTime = (currHr*60)+currtMin;` implicit conversion loses integer precision long to int

Comment: i have already mentioned convert NSInteger to (int).  int nowTime = (int)(currHr*60)+(int)currtMin

Comment: Dude integer conversion woks but, your 2nd if condition gets false when nowTime is `1:15pm` between `8:35am` and `4.:43pm` :(

Comment: First of all you have to use 24Hr format and am/pm logic wont work in checking time whether it falls between start time & end time or not. Why this, because if you check for time 4:00 pm between 4:00 am & 5:00 pm. Minutes conversion of 4:00 am & 4:00 pm will give same value and logic fails here. So think over it and use 24Hr format. If you really want to use am/pm logic then use date also with time there is different logic for checking datetime :)

Comment: Time is coming from server i can't change any thing in that :( only fix thing is `startTime` always in `am` and `endTime` in `pm` now can you please help me in the logic ?

Comment: Bro your code crashes `-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbfebfb6ae0`  here `NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];` value of `unitFlag is 96` and `date is 8:16`

Comment: check the attached screenshot. code works fine for me no crashes. you can check with other identifier "NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian" in place of "NSCalendarIdentifierIndian". I have checked with both the identifier.

Comment: check the updated code. without any identifier also code works fine with expected result :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75025/discussion-between-krunal-and-uttam-sinha).

Comment: Thanx for helping, problem solved +1 for your answer