# Issue to get only time of NSDate and ignore date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I found many questions like mine, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I have in my Core Data database a list of openings hours.
I would like to know if, for a given date, it's opened or closed.

But I don't want check on date. Only on hours, minutes and seconds.

Here the model of my object Opening:

- NSNumber * days;
- NSDate * start;
- NSDate * end;

My problem is I have all the time exactly 42 min and 30 sec more than the original date after extracting time from my NSDate object.

Here my code:

```
NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit flags = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;

for (Opening * opening in openingsForDate) {

    NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:opening.start];
    NSDateComponents *date3Components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:opening.end];

    NSDate *date1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
    NSDate *date2 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];
    NSDate *date3 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date3Components];

    NSLog(@"%@ => %@", date, date1);
    NSLog(@"%@ => %@", opening.start, date2);
    NSLog(@"%@ => %@", opening.end, date3);
}
```

Here the output:

```
2017-01-25 22:10:41 +0000 => 0001-01-01 22:53:11 +0000
2017-01-25 11:00:00 +0000 => 0001-01-01 11:42:30 +0000
2017-01-25 22:00:00 +0000 => 0001-01-01 22:42:30 +0000
```

Any ideas ?
Thank you.

**EDIT:** Solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579720/2061450) !

Comment: Should I maybe store NSNumber instead of NSDate. So convert hours, minutes and second into NSTimeInterval and store this in my core data database ? However, I don't understand why I have 42 min and 30 seconds more ^^

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting back to NSDate, just use NSDateComponents hour, minute and second properties to calculate seconds from midnight. Then you can just compare the integers.

```
NSInteger compareSeconds = date1Components.second + (date1Components.minute*60) + (date1Components.hour*60*60);
NSInteger openingSeconds = date2Components.second + (date2Components.minute*60) + (date2Components.hour*60*60);
NSInteger closingSeconds = date3Components.second + (date3Components.minute*60) + (date3Components.hour*60*60);

if (openingSeconds<compareSeconds && closingSeconds>compareSeconds){
    // Open
} else {
    // Closed
}
```

Comment: Not working properly. See my edit. Thank you anyway :)